# Configure the Matplotlib figure size so that the font within the graphics matches the font in the text

Tags: graphics

I would like to configure the size of a figure produced by Matplotlib so that the font within the graphics matches the font size in the text.

The following Python script produces the figure using Tex fonts.

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl
import matplotlib

matplotlib.rcParams["text.usetex"] = True
matplotlib.rcParams["font.family"] = "serif"
matplotlib.rcParams["font.size"] = "18"

x = np.linspace(0.0, 2.0 * np.pi, 1000)
y = np.sin(x)
#
pl.figure(figsize=(4, 3))
pl.plot(x, y, "-")
pl.xlabel("x")
pl.ylabel("y")
pl.title("The sine function")
pl.savefig("sine-function.pdf", bbox_inches="tight")
```

Then I created a LaTeX document which inserts this figure.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{sine-function.pdf}
\end{center}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: The result]

The figure is much larger than required. I could downsize it e.g. with width=0.5\textwidth, but this is unsatisfactory, because, no matter how I set the width parameter, I cannot be sure that the font size in the text matches the font size in the figure.

How to configure this correctly?

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to configure the font size correctly right from Matplotlib.
The correct script is the following. The font size is set to 10. In order to produce a correct graph, I add to downsize the figure with the `figsize` argument.

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl
import matplotlib

matplotlib.rcParams["text.usetex"] = True
matplotlib.rcParams["font.family"] = "serif"
matplotlib.rcParams["font.size"] = "10"

x = np.linspace(0.0, 2.0 * np.pi, 1000)
y = np.sin(x)
#
pl.figure(figsize=(2.0, 1.5))
pl.plot(x, y, "-")
pl.xlabel("x")
pl.ylabel("y")
pl.title("The sine function")
pl.savefig("sine-function.pdf", bbox_inches="tight")
```

Then I used the following tex document. Since the font size in the PDF is 10, I do not have to change its width.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics{sine-function.pdf}
\end{center}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: The correct result]

which is the correct result.